# Knockout js Update viewmodel after ajax post

Tags: ajax, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am using knockout js and the knockout mapping plugin.

**My problem is after calling the ajax post my view (ui) is not updating.**
Only if I reload the page the data will be updated.

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: WorkData">
    <td data-bind="text: id"></td>
    <td data-bind="text: user_name"></td>
    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-bind="click: $parent.postTmpData" role="button">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
</tbody>

<script>
    function ViewModel() {
        var self = this;
        var data = <?php echo json_encode($this->data); ?> ;
        self.WorkData = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

        self.postTmpData = function(entry) {
            $.post("<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>/work/confirmWorkPost/", entry, function(returnedData) {
                ko.mapping.fromJS(returnedData, self);
            })
        }
    }
    ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the solution for me:

```
ko.mapping.fromJS(JSON.parse(returnedData), self.WorkData);
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `returnedData` what you want to replace `WorkData` with? It's only possible if they are in the same structure. In that case, try this:

```
$.post("<?php echo Config::get('URL'); ?>/work/confirmWorkPost/", entry, function(returnedData) {
    ko.mapping.fromJS({'WorkData': returnedData}, self);
})
```

Comment: I tried that and it did not help. the view (html) with "data-bind="foreach: WorkData" is still not updating

Comment: Still no idea about my problem? I would really like to find a solution.

Comment: as I said, unless I can debug I can't tell what's wrong... Any way you can share the project, at least the relevant parts?